# How to regenerate bombs in witcher 3?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I am not able to regenerate my bombs and potion after meditating,though I have high level alcohols(like alcohest,dwarven spirit etc).

Comment: Alcohol should refill the bombs. From searching the web, most players who have the problem of bombs not refilling have a mod called "friendly UI" installed, and apparently you can switch refilling bombs on meditating by pressing F4, according to this Steam forum thread: https://steamcommunity.com/app/292030/discussions/0/451852225140232493/